# Fastest/best way to add columns to a pandas dataframe from a dict of numpy arrays with the same df length?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, coding-style

Probably is a easy question, I've searched but i can't find the solution.

My code is something like

```py
data_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2012-02-22', '3', 'a', 6],
    ['2012-02-23', '3.2', 'g', 8],
    ['2012-02-24', '5.2', 'l', 2],
    ['2012-02-25', '1.4', 'i', 4]],
    columns=['date', '1', '2', '3'])
dict_a = {
    'a': np.array([False, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
    'b': np.array([True, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
    'c': np.array([False, True, True, False], dtype='bool'),
}
```

and I would like to have a df like this

```py
              1  2  3      a      b      c
date                                      
2012-02-22    3  a  6  False   True  False
2012-02-23  3.2  g  8   True   True   True
2012-02-24  5.2  l  2  False  False   True
2012-02-25  1.4  i  4  False  False  False
```

until now the best way I've found is this but it seems hacky to me

```py
data_df = data_df.set_index('date')
df_dict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_a)
df_dict['date'] = data_df.index
df_dict = df_dict.set_index('date')
df_new = pd.merge(data_df, df_dict, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

there is a faster/better way to achieve it?

#### EDIT: Results

Thank you all for the very fast responses.
I've made some timing and (so far) looks like that with the given data the fastest is the 1st.

```py
def df_new1():
    data_df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['2012-02-22', '3', 'a', 6],
        ['2012-02-23', '3.2', 'g', 8],
        ['2012-02-24', '5.2', 'l', 2],
        ['2012-02-25', '1.4', 'i', 4]],
        columns=['date', '1', '2', '3'])

    dict_a = {
        'a1': np.array([False, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
        'b1': np.array([True, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
        'c1': np.array([False, True, True, False], dtype='bool'),
    }
    return pd.concat((data_df, pd.DataFrame(dict_a)), axis=1).set_index('date')


def df_new2():
    data_df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['2012-02-22', '3', 'a', 6],
        ['2012-02-23', '3.2', 'g', 8],
        ['2012-02-24', '5.2', 'l', 2],
        ['2012-02-25', '1.4', 'i', 4]],
        columns=['date', '1', '2', '3'])

    dict_a = {
        'a1': np.array([False, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
        'b1': np.array([True, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
        'c1': np.array([False, True, True, False], dtype='bool'),
    }
    return data_df.assign(**dict_a).set_index('date')


def df_new3():
    data_df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['2012-02-22', '3', 'a', 6],
        ['2012-02-23', '3.2', 'g', 8],
        ['2012-02-24', '5.2', 'l', 2],
        ['2012-02-25', '1.4', 'i', 4]],
        columns=['date', '1', '2', '3'])

    dict_a = {
        'a1': np.array([False, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
        'b1': np.array([True, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
        'c1': np.array([False, True, True, False], dtype='bool'),
    }
    return data_df.join(pd.DataFrame(dict_a)).set_index('date')


def df_new4():
    data_df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['2012-02-22', '3', 'a', 6],
        ['2012-02-23', '3.2', 'g', 8],
        ['2012-02-24', '5.2', 'l', 2],
        ['2012-02-25', '1.4', 'i', 4]],
        columns=['date', '1', '2', '3'])

    dict_a = {
        'a1': np.array([False, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
        'b1': np.array([True, True, False, False], dtype='bool'),
        'c1': np.array([False, True, True, False], dtype='bool'),
    }
    for keys in dict_a:
        data_df[keys] = dict_a[keys]
    return data_df.set_index('date')

print('df_new1', timeit(df_new1, number=1000))
print('df_new2', timeit(df_new2, number=1000))
print('df_new3', timeit(df_new3, number=1000))
print('df_new4', timeit(df_new4, number=1000))
```

```py
df_new1 2.0431520210004237
df_new2 2.6708478379987355
df_new3 2.4773063749998983
df_new4 2.910699995998584
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.concat` on `axis=1`, then set the index

```
pd.concat((data_df,pd.DataFrame(dict_a)),axis=1).set_index("date")

              1  2  3      a      b      c
date                                      
2012-02-22    3  a  6  False   True  False
2012-02-23  3.2  g  8   True   True   True
2012-02-24  5.2  l  2  False  False   True
2012-02-25  1.4  i  4  False  False  False
```

Comment: Look like this is the fastest code with the given data. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
for keys in dict_a:
    data_df[keys]=dict_a[keys]
```

Do note that the length of data in dict has to be equal to length of data in dataframe

Comment: I accept this as result as at the moment look like is the fastest. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake. I've forgot to add the `.set_index('date')` at the end as the required code has it. Looks like this little change added a lot of work and now the code is the slowest. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Try `DataFrame.assign`:

```
data_df.assign(**dict_a)
```

---

```
         date    1  2  3      a      b      c
0  2012-02-22    3  a  6  False   True  False
1  2012-02-23  3.2  g  8   True   True   True
2  2012-02-24  5.2  l  2  False  False   True
3  2012-02-25  1.4  i  4  False  False  False
```

Comment: This is very elegant and clean, I will probably use it as is the most concise. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `join`:

```
data_df.join(pd.DataFrame(dict_a)).set_index('date')
              1  2  3      a      b      c
date                                      
2012-02-22    3  a  6  False   True  False
2012-02-23  3.2  g  8   True   True   True
2012-02-24  5.2  l  2  False  False   True
2012-02-25  1.4  i  4  False  False  False
```